# Ignore specific characters before a delimiter with RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create two regular expressions to capture the needed characters of European license plates.

It's important to mention that

- the delimiter separating the **country** from the rest (first letter) is always an `* (asterisk) or a - (hyphen)`
- the delimiter separating the **district** from the other characters on the right is always `a - (hyphen)`
- The district can also contain letters such as ä,ö,ü

The license plates look like this:

```
A*S-XXXPA
A*SL-XXXPC
A*SL-XXXSD
A*HA-XXXHV
D*R-XXXXX
D*TS-XXXXX
A*VB-1XXXXX
```

The RegExs I use for capturing the countries and the district are the following.

```
String country = "^([A-Z]{1,3})";
String district = "\\h*(\\p{L}{1,3})[-*]";
```

Once I get the needed information out of my Strings, I remove the information I don't need with java code, here's the code piece:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
        
        country_region = matcher.group(1);
        country_region = country_region.replace("*", "");
        country_region = country_region.replace("-", "");
        country_region = country_region.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");            

    }
```

My regex capturing the countries works fine, here's an example:

- https://regex101.com/r/jfhSJN/1

The one I'm having troubles with is the RegEx I use to capture districts. At the moment it also catches the countries...

- https://regex101.com/r/57ZE9O/1

I guess I could just remove the asterisk at the end of my RegEx, but I do not think it's the cleanest way to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with the district regex is that `\h*` matches any zero or more horizontal whitespaces. So the match can also occur at the start of string.

Since you want to get a match after a horizontal whitespace, `*` or `-`, you can use

```java
[*\h-](\p{L}{1,3})[-*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IzTqEx/2). Here, `[*\h-]` matches a `*`, a horizontal whitespace or a `-` char.

However, it makes sense to use a regex to match the stirng while capturing all parts into groups:

```java
^([A-Z]{1,3})[\h*-](\p{L}{1,3})[-*](.+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/57ZE9O/4). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z]{1,3})` - Group 1: one, two or three uppercase letters
- `[\h*-]` - a horizontal whitespace, `*` or `-`
- `(\p{L}{1,3})` - Group 2: one to three any Unicode letters
- `[-*]` - a `-` or `*` char
- `(.+)` - Group 3: all text till the end of string/line.

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew - thanks a lot for the great explanation and answer. In my case, I'm explicitly looking to work without groups in order to prevent changes in the java code. Would that be possible just for the districts?

Comment: @Djabone Yes, see `(?<=[*\h-])\p{L}{1,3}(?=[-*])` [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/IzTqEx/3).

Comment: Could you please let me know if I got it well? ```(?<=[*\h-]) positive lookbehind - searches for - but only if there's a * before it? \p{L}{1,3} matches any letter from any language between 1 and 3 characters. ?=[-*] lost me here```. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Djabone No. `(?<=[*\h-])` - a positive lookahead that requires either `*`, or `-` or a hor. whitespace immediately to the left of the current location. You understand `\p{L}{1,3}` correctly. `(?=[\h-])` is a positive lookahead that requires either a hor. whitespace or `-` immediately to the right of the current location.